# Ionic Android Application not building

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\myproject>ionic cordova build android
[WARN] Not performing Ionic build for project type: ionic1.

> cordova build android
>   Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\myproject\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\myproject

add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Tuladhar\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.

```
    at build_859uxik73yildsrgrru9xamjo.run(C:\Users\Tuladhar\WebstormProjects\myproject\platforms\android\build.gradle:141)
```

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 22.164 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
  >   Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for cxcpcn2de84br0eekalu3p9nv (C:\Users\Tuladhar.gradle\caches\3.3\scripts-remapped\build_c7ur6ql0tv1x27ryhuthd38ad\cxcpcn2de84br0eekalu3p9nv\cp_proj1efd45104ffa2d33563b85b9edda76e3).
  >   Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
  >   Could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for cxcpcn2de84br0eekalu3p9nv (C:\Users\Tuladhar.gradle\caches\3.3\scripts-remapped\build_c7ur6ql0tv1x27ryhuthd38ad\cxcpcn2de84br0eekalu3p9nv\cp_proj1efd45104ffa2d33563b85b9edda76e3).
  >   Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).

Comment: Try to remove android platform using "ionic cordova platform remove android" then open command line as administrator and try adding android platform again using "ionic cordova platform add android"

Answer (score 1):

1.Remove platforms (you can delete it from folder)

2.Remove node_modules (you can delete it from folder)

3.Upgrade your ionic-cli version to the latest (`npm update -g ionic` )

4.run `npm install`

5.run `ionic cordova platform add android`

6.run `ionic cordova run android`

Try these steps accordingly and it will work. If not try updating android api and sdk tools and re-do the steps.

Comment: I've tried these steps carefully. Also did I updated sdk tools and re-followed the steps. But it is still not working.